# Incorrect output of uniq -c

Tags: bash, count, uniq

So, basically Im trying to count how many appearances of each word shows up on a Chef recipes file.

```
7-zip
ant
ant
ant
apache2
apache2
apache2
apache2
api-example-v1
api-products-v3
apt
apt
apt
ark
ark
ark
artifactory
artifactory
artifactory-wrapper
atp-cache-clear
```

So it should be as easy as "uniq -c myfile.txt" ( the file is sorted already ), but the problem I am having is when I do it I get this output :

```
1 7-zip
2 ant
1 ant
3 apache2
1 apache2
1 api-example-v1
1 api-products-v3
2 apt
1 apt
2 ark
1 ark
1 artifactory
1 artifactory
1 artifactory-wrapper
1 atp-cache-clear
1 atp-cache-clear
2 atpc-deployer
1 atpc-deployer
2 atpc-wrapper
1 atpc-wrapper
```

As you can see the output is incorrect. For instance, "ark" should only appear once with a count of 3. And so on for all the items.

I already did this with no issues with another file and the output was correct.

As a Note, I already tried "cat -T myfile.txt" to see the non printable characters to see if something was there that I could not see but nothing shows up.

I also stripped the trailing and leading spaces from each line of the file.

What else might I be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cat -T` only shows tabs. Use `cat -A` to show all special characters.

Comment: $ cat -A wholething.txt |  head -20
7-zip^M$
ant$
ant$
ant^M$
apache2$
apache2$
apache2$
apache2^M$
api-example-v1^M$
api-products-v3^M$
apt$
apt$
apt^M$
ark$
ark$
ark^M$
artifactory$
artifactory^M$
artifactory-wrapper^M$
atp-cache-clear$

What a fool! Thanks so much I can see what was happening now.